# How to make your Drupal 8 response cachable by browser?

Tags: symfony, drupal, browser-cache, drupal-8

**Update**: Reposted on [StackExchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/285160/how-to-make-your-drupal-8-response-cachable-by-browser).

---

I am working on a Drupal Controller implementation that would return a generated image as response. I used Symfony's [Response](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) and I was trying to add ETag header to it:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  public static function viewGraph(string $id, Request $request) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setEtag($etag); // some etag genrated from $id
    if ($response->isNotModified($request)) {
      return $response;
    }
    // ...
    return $response;
  }

}
```

I expected to see the `"ETag"` header in my response. But there is nothing. I've even tried [CacheableResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheableResponse.php/class/CacheableResponse/8.2.x) and it didn't work as well.

What's wrong with my approach? What is the right approach to it?